# Django + New Relic performance benchmarking

Tags: django, performance, automation, newrelic

I've got a Django web app with a complicated data model that's experiencing performance issues. Using New Relic, I was pretty much instantaneously able to isolate what the problem is. But there are a number of different solutions I can try. What I'd like to do is be able to benchmark the efficacy of different solutions in various combinations.

In my mind, one way of doing this by hand would be to make a Django model that stores configuration flags outside of my settings file, so I could change them through the admin instead of redeploying. Then I could monitor New Relic and record the metrics into a spreadsheet.

But I feel like that would be a poor reinvention of something people probably do all the time. Is there a good methodology for doing this without a whole bunch of manual labor?

Comment: I'm actually looking for something like this too. Upvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the overall methodology, but another option to check out that I was really happy with was [Tracelytics](http://www.tracelytics.com/).

Also, another thing to help with your question would be the project [django-waffle](https://github.com/jsocol/django-waffle) which I've never used, but seems like it'd be nice for changing flags/settings from admin!

Comment: Django-waffle definitely seems like a useful component to this whole enterprise. I suppose I could write a simple view to make an HTTP-activated controller to automate the combinations and a simple script to generate page requests. 

That would leave automated results collection and collation with settings, as well as proper interpretation of those results.

Comment: To be more helpful, can you be more specific about speed problems? Maybe screen shots/information from your profiling?

Good idea @fmendez

Answer (score 1):

If you recorded a deployment in NewRelic when you push some configuration changes then you could analyse the performance before and after using the Change log or Change report through the deployments dashboard.

Recording a deployment is as easy as a curl command

```
curl -H "x-api-key:REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_API_KEY" -d "deployment[app_name]=REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_APP_NAME" https://api.newrelic.com/deployments.xml
```

You can read more details about deployments here:

http://docs.newrelic.com/docs/applications-menu/deployments-dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Aside from Waffle, you may want to look into other settings backends, like [Menagerie](https://github.com/disqus/menagerie), which retrieves its settings from Zookeeper, and updates them on changes, too.